# How can I do this type of combination?

Tags: c

I am learning programming and I have a basic problem (I think):

I have the following integers: 1 2 3
I need all the combinations between these integers like this:

1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 1&2 ; 1&3 ; 2&3 ; 1&2&3

There can be no repetitions (example 1 & 2 and 2 & 1)

However it has to be for N numbers

If you could guide me it would be very helpful

Comment: Counting from 0 to (1<<N)-1 goes through all combinations of N bits.

Comment: For N=3 you want a loop that counts from 1 to 7. Then convert the numbers to binary. So you get 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111. Each bit represents one of the integers. For example 001 is the combination `1`, 010 is the combination `2`, 011 is the combination `1&2`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it must be for N numbers

Comment: Yes, for N numbers, count from 1 to 2^N-1. Then you have N binary (0 or 1) bits. 0 means *don't* include the corresponding number in the combination. 1 means *do* include the number.